# Need to loop over pandas df set of two consecutive column names in each iteration to create separate pivots in different excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop, pivot

Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE':['200701','200702','200703','200704'],
    'A':['35','42','43','25'],'B':['33','40','39','28'],
    'DIFFERENCE OF A&B':['2','2','4','-3'],
    'C':['26','28','24','19'],'D':['20','25','30','25'],
    'DIFFERENCE OF C&D':['6','3','-6','-6']
})
```

Expected output:

Iteration 1 pivot:

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['DATE'],values=['A','B','DIFFERENCE OF A&B'],aggfunc='sum')
```

Iteration 2 pivot:

```
pivot2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['DATE'],values=['C','D','DIFFERENCE OF C&D'],aggfunc='sum')
```

and so on for next 2 consecutive columns in values of pivot.

Please help me I am struggling a lot.

Comment: Amit, are you wondering, how to create a loop, where on each iteration, you look at the index values containing `'DIFFERENCE OF'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pivot_table() function doesn't seem to do anything to the dataframe example you gave, nonetheless, maybe this will work. See comments inline.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE':['200701','200702','200703','200704'],
    'A':['35','42','43','25'],'B':['33','40','39','28'],
    'DIFFERENCE OF A&B':['2','2','4','-3'],
    'C':['26','28','24','19'],'D':['20','25','30','25'],
    'DIFFERENCE OF C&D':['6','3','-6','-6']
})

df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True) # set the index to DATE

for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 3): # assumes your columns are multiple of 3
    print(df.iloc[: , i:i+3 ]) # find the dataset for successive three columns
    # the next line gives the same output as previous line
    # print(pd.pivot_table(df.iloc[: , i:i+3 ],index=df.iloc[: , i:i+3 ].index,values=df.iloc[: , i:i+3 ].columns.to_list(),aggfunc='sum'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonathan , it solved at least my basic loop problem, the only thing is I want each iteration of pivot on different excel sheets, how can I do that.

Comment: @Jonathon also I don't know why pivot is not keeping the order of my df columns it is getting changed how should I retain them?

Comment: Hi. There are plenty of examples of looping through data frames to excel on SO. Try searching and your post code in a new question please.